# Теория вероятности и математическая статистика: задача о билетах

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Преподаватель предложил на досуге подумать над следующей задачей:
Есть `n` учеников. Ученик выучил `m` билетов. Всего билетов больше, чем `n`.
Найти вероятность того, что если он зайдет в аудиторию `k`-ым, то ему попадется билет, который он выучил.

Comment: Какая разница, каким он зайдёт?

Comment: @Igor Но часть билетов, которые учил этот студент, будет в общем и целом оставаться прежней...

Comment: @Igor Это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @Akina Разница в том, что билеты, которые он учил, могут вытянуть студенты, которые зашли до него.

Comment: "Преподаватель предложил на досуге подумать .." - ну так подумайте

Comment: @Kromster Видимо, досуга не хватает :)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что здесь не выполняют задания за студентов.

Answer (score 5):

Эххх... представь себе, что ты расписАл ВСЕ варианты расположения билетов в "колоде". В виде офигительной таблицы из X! строк, где X - количество билетов. Соответственно, колонка номер k этой таблицы отображает для каждого отдельного варианта номер билета, который возьмёт k-й студент.

Надо ли объяснять, что если вырезать из этой таблицы всю эту колонку и посчитать, какое количество записей каждого номера вопросов в ней присутствует, то обнаружится, что оно одинаково для всех номеров?

Надо ли объяснять, что описанное выше никак не зависит от того, какую из колонок мы вырежем?

Надо ли объяснять, что результат не зависит от того, что мы какие-то колонки поменяем местами (ну скажем чтобы они располагались в том порядке, в каком студенты тащат билеты из пачки)?

А в общем, вероятность равна A/B, где A - количество выученных билетов, а B - их общее количество. А от количества студентов и того, каким пойдёт конкретный студент, эта вероятность в принципе не зависит.

Answer (score 3):

Вероятность будет одна и та же - потому что предыдущие студенты будут тянуть билеты с точно такой же вероятностью :) Так что вероятность должна быть одна и та же - `m/N`, где `N` - количество билетов.

Если не верите - вот эксперимент. Выученные билеты - от `0` до `m-1`. Билеты перемешиваются. Если `k`-й билет меньше `m` - это и есть успех.
Почему эта модель адекватна - подумайте сами.

Код привожу, результаты смотрите [тут](http://ideone.com/kA9rJT). Можете поэкспериментировать самостоятельно...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

double experiment(int n, int m, int k, int count = 10000)
{
    int succ = 0;
    vector<int> b;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        b.push_back(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
    {
        random_shuffle(b.begin(), b.end());
        if (b[k] < m) succ++;
    }
    return double(succ)/count;
}

int main()
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 30; ++k)
    {
        cout << "k = " << setw(2) << k << " Success = " << setw(10) << experiment(50,10,k) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем, ты не учитываешь то, что если на l < k -ом месте зайдет человек, то у него может попасться билет, который ты учил. Например 30 человек, ты выучил 15, заходишь 25ым, тогда может получиться так, что 25 первых студентов разобрали 15 твоих выученных

Comment: @KamilNHOT А может получиться, что тебе оставили только выученные билеты. Это независимые события.

Comment: Может. Тебя интересует что? **ВЕРОЯТНОСТЬ** Вот и считай вероятность :) А вообще, дорогой, иди читай учебник. Если так ничего и  не понял... И на всякий случай - здесь, вообще-то, принято обращение на "вы"...

Comment: я слегка фамильярный человек(